# Calling MySQL procedure results in NULL database variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL procedure that sets different database variables:

```sql
    CREATE PROCEDURE NEWWEEK()
    BEGIN
        SET @FECHA = (date_sub(curdate(), interval WEEKDAY(curdate()) DAY));
        SET @WEEKNAME = REGEXP_REPLACE(concat('w', @FECHA), '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]', '');
        INSERT INTO ARCHIVO(FECHA) VALUES (@FECHA);
        SET @ARCHIVOID = (SELECT ID FROM ARCHIVO WHERE FECHA = @FECHA);
    END//
```

Now, when I call it from the MySQL terminal, it works flawlessly. However, when I call it through a MySQLi query:

```php
$sql = $conn->query("Select * from ARCHIVO where FECHA BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND now()");
$row = $sql->fetch_assoc();
if($sql->num_rows < 1){
    $conn->query("CALL NEWWEEK()");
}
```

The procedures works well (ARCHIVO has now a new row and @FECHA in the third line,for example, is not null) but once the query finishes, those variables aren't saved in the database;

```sql
mysql> SELECT @FECHA, @WEEKNAME, @ARCHIVOID;
+------------+-----------+------------+
| @FECHA     | @WEEKNAME | @ARCHIVOID |
+------------+-----------+------------+   /*From Terminal */
| 2022-09-26 | w20220926 |          1 |
+------------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

```sql
mysql> SELECT @FECHA, @WEEKNAME, @ARCHIVOID;
+----------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| @FECHA         | @WEEKNAME            | @ARCHIVOID             |
+----------------+----------------------+------------------------+    /* PHP */
| NULL           | NULL                 | NULL                   |
+----------------+----------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Those are *session* variables. Obviously, they are only available in the same session. What 's the point requesting these  variables from another session? did you try to select them in the same session?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know, I thought they were database variables stored permanently. Do I have to store them in a table or is there another option? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I suppose you have to make your mind first, what these variables are for.